# Write-Output format

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have few groups and need to export the result into one file. However I tried ways but can't get it work. If I use `$group` then the format isn't right. I would want to still keep the select result such as Name and the count. What code should I add to get it work?

```
$group2 | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq "User" } |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    Get-ADUser -Properties canonicalName |
    Select-Object @{Name='container';Expression={($_.canonicalname -split '/')[2,3]}}, Count |
    Group-Object container
    Select Name, Count

$group3 | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq "User" } |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    Get-ADUser -Properties canonicalName |
    Select-Object @{Name='container';Expression={($_.canonicalname -split '/')[2,3]}}, Count |
    Group-Object container
    Select Name, Count

$group4 | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq "User" } |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    Get-ADUser -Properties canonicalName |
    Select-Object @{Name='container';Expression={($_.canonicalname -split '/')[2,3]}}, Count |
    Group-Object container
    Select Name, Count

Write-Output User, $Group2, $group3, Group4 |
    Out-File -FilePath C:\Temp\Group_User$timestamp.csv -Append
```

Comment: what are you getting?.....what would you like to get?

Comment: You don't store the results of your pipelines anywhere..

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: `$resultX = $groupX | ...`. And since each pipeline does the same you may want to put the pipeline code in a function. Anyway, please provide sample input and both the desired and actual output you want to create from that input.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear as to what you want to achieve. You should give us a few lines of the desired output.
Then folks will now what it is that you want.
Having said that, as a scripter you want to try and make your code do itterations rather than writing the same code over and over.
So for you, you should look into a foreach loop.
This way, your code gets repeated as many times as you have groups.

```
$groups = @("group1","group2")
$report = @()
foreach ($group in $groups){
 $report +=    $group | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
        Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq "User" } |
        Select-Object -Unique |
        Get-ADUser -Properties Name,canonicalname |  
        Select Name, canonicalname
} 

$report
```